# Is there any secure way to display user submitted html report?

Tags: security, content-security-policy

I am working on a data share website that allow users to publish their HTML reports. As the whole website is under the same domain, my concern is it will bring security risks if the HTML files contain malicious scripts.

Suppose if user1 upload a zip file `my-report.zip` that contains all contents of a website, and then it will be published under https://example.org/user1/my-report.

What I want to know is, when user2 access the report published by user1, is there anything I need to do to ensure user2 is secure? (e.g. His/Her auth token won't be stolen by user1, etc).

Maybe I could make use of CSP policy or something, for example,

```
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src 'self';
```

But I don't know to what extent it would be considered sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is by no means trivial. I'll try to summarize my way of thinking about this problem.

1. Before we even start thinking about security of the solution be aware, that there are some safety concerns as well. People may upload stuff that is wrong, offensive or illegal (child porn, scam). There is no solution to deal with it on the technical level. Make sure you have some answer to that.
2. If possible, consider preventing deployments of custom css/js files. Assume all functionality is provided by you and that people upload only the html content. They may or may not reference the libs you provide, but never their own. Use CSP to prevent that.
3. Think about the secrets you are passing in every request. Will the html content be able to process it? If you are using cookies, set the `HTTPOnly` flag. If you are using custom headers with secrets, well, this is the reason why we want to prevent custom js from running in the first place.
4. Turn on some security headers on your side. Prevent using `iframe` with `X-Frame-Options`, turn on `X-XSS-Protection`.

In a case like yours I would request a pentest over the solution I provide. The playground for attackers is huge.